# Showing application icon on windows8's windows

Tags: windows-8, icons, window-manager, usability

Is there any way to display the application icon on it's window borders. like it used to on older version of windows on the top left corner?

that new window is beautiful and looks great and have great usability with distraction free on a small 10" screen. but on my huge monitor with tons of windows floating around, i never know if the browser window is chrome or firefox!

is there any way to get those icons back?

Comment: knowing windows, i'm almost sure they have some flag in the register to enable that back again.... but yeah, if it's only 3rd party hacks i'd move away, unless it is open source.

Comment: I don't know of any such flag for the DWM and doubt it exists, but maybe someone else does.

Comment: @Karan so upvote and satiate your curiosity when someone answers :D

Comment: actually, i think this is specific to my text editor, firefox and chrome. dammed applications that tries to skin the OS regular look and feel.... will probably close this. every other window have the application icons on the left! explorer even changes it to represent if you are looking at a network, computer, driver or folder!